# Inheritance method call triggers Typescript compiler error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webstorm

I am having an issue with webstorm typescript compiler. I have the following classes

```
export class rootData{
  id:string
  //...

  constructor(){
    //...
  }

  insert = ():Promise<any> =>{
    //...
  }
}

class child extends rootData {
  //...   

  constructor(){
     super();
  }

  insert = ():Promise<any> => {
        return super.insert();
    }
}
```

So typing "super", I see all rootData public methods in the intellisense. But after setting super.insert(), I get the following error :

TS2340: Only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword

Tried in TS playground, it is working (simplified version thought).

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: After checking the compiled javascript, the call of the super method is there. So the compiler gives an error but compiles...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because `super` calls are redirected to the `prototype` you cannot use a `property` and need to use a `method` i.e. can't use `= ()=>`.

Fixed code:

```
export class rootData{
  id:string
  //...

  constructor(){
    //...
  }

  insert():Promise<any>{
    //...
  }
}

class child extends rootData {
  //...   

  constructor(){
     super();
  }

  insert():Promise<any> {
        return super.insert();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had this problem also. Thanks for posting this. It's unfortunate about the design of TypeScript because I use '=>' in my object member definitions to be sure to capure 'this' and not have to call bind() every time i need a member function that operates on the object. So now i have this uglyness that all functions are using => and capture this except for the functions that happen to be used in an override, which need bind(). This creates very ugly and confusing code. Seems like there would be a better way to do super calls rather than simply disallow '=>'.

Comment: @basarat Please keep me honest and let me know if my answer isn't valid as well.

Comment: regarding the issue posted above about needing `bind()` when using this approach, see [the typescript book](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/master/docs/arrow-functions.md#tip-arrow-functions-and-inheritance) (written by the answerer here!) for how to work around that need @user2080225

Comment: Where are class properties located? Aren they not located in prototype? How can they be accessed?

Comment: FWIW, this answer works for me IF the Typescript target = `es2015` or later. It does not work for `es5`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an "internal" method that is protected that actually performs the logic.  Since you can't call it outside of the class, the this will always be in the correct context.

```
export class rootData{
  id:string
  //...

  constructor(){
    //...
  }

  insert = ():Promise<any> =>{
    return this.insertInternal();
  }

  protected insertInternal():Promise<any>{
    //...
  }
}

class child extends rootData {
  //...   

  constructor(){
     super();
  }

  protected insertInternal():Promise<any> {
        return super.insertInternal();
    }
}
```

You can view a TypeScript Playgound version of it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.greetInternal()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20greetInternal()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Greeter2%20extends%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greetInternal()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Overroad%20Greet%20by%20overriding%20%22%20%2B%20super.greetInternal()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter2(%22world%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0D%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20%22Say%20Hello%22%3B%0D%0Abutton.onclick%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(greeter.greet())%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B).