# Error when calling super.method() on a method that is defined as an arrow function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

When a method is defined in a base class as an arrow function, when calling that method in a derived class via super.method(), I get an error "Only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword.ts(2340)", Even though the method was defined as public.

[image: Screenshot]

I understand that in an arrow function the context is lexical. This would affect the value of `this` and `super` in an arrow function, but in the image above Sun.met1 is not defined as an arrow function, so I don't see why it can't access Father.met.

Comment: This is not an editor thing. The error shows when running `npm run tsc`

Comment: Environment: Create-React-App --typescript mode. VSCode

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by changing the `target` in your `tsconfig.json` to from `es5` to `es6` or newer:

```
"target": "es6"
```

I'm not sure if this is by-design or not but have opened https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32121 to get clarification from the TS team

Alternatively, just use normal methods instead of arrow functions

Comment: Also covered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088947/inheritance-method-call-triggers-typescript-compiler-error but it doesn't explain why this is an error  under `target: es5` but allowed under `es6`