# TypeScript - Error when try to call super setter/getter (reproduce only with prod task)

Tags: angular, typescript

When I try call super getter or super setter when overriding properties? I get an error:
TS2340: Only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword.

This error I get only when execute 'ng build --configuration=production --stats-json'

This error appeared after the I update Angular from v7.2.11 to v8.0.3 (TypeScrypt from v3.1.6 to v3.4.5).

With Angular v7.2.11 and TypeScrypt v3.1.6 there is no such error.
I don't use targeting to es5.
I tried to target es2015, es2016, es2017, but I get the same error in each case.

Code example

```
export abstract class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {
    get selected(): boolean {
        return super.selected;
    }
    set selected(selected: boolean) {
        super.selected = selected;
    }
}
export abstract class ParentComponent {
    public get selected(): boolean {
        return this._selected;
    }
    public set selected(value: boolean) {
        this._selected = value;
    }
}
```

My tsconfig:

```
{
        "compileOnSave": false,
        "compilerOptions": {
                "downlevelIteration": true,
                "outDir": "./dist",
                "baseUrl": ".",
                "sourceMap": true,
                "declaration": false,
                "moduleResolution": "node",
                "module": "esnext",
                "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
                "experimentalDecorators": true,
                "noEmitHelpers": true,
                "importHelpers": true,
                "esModuleInterop": true,
                "target": "es2015",
                "typeRoots": [
                       "node_modules/@types"
                ],
                "lib": [
                       "es2017",
                       "dom"
                ],
                "paths": {
                   ...
                }
        },
        "exclude": [
        ...
       ]
}
```

I expected my code to start working after I switched to “target”: “es2015”, but it didn't.
Maybe there is any errors in my config?

I also do not use the arrow functions, so as far as I understand, my problem is not related to the context.

Comment: if `ChildComponent` extends `ParentComponent`, just delcare `ParentComponent` getters and setters as protected, so you can use them as `super.selected` (or `this.selected`)

Comment: @CapitanFindus I tried to do it, but it did not solve my problem. explicit indication of the decorator does not solve this problem in my case. I edited the example, because there was an inaccuracy in the original version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheritance method call triggers Typescript compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088947/inheritance-method-call-triggers-typescript-compiler-error)

Comment: @BernardPagoaga I don't use the arrow functions, so as far as I understand, this problem is not related to the context. And, as far as I understand the problem of [Inheritance method call triggers Typescript compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088947/inheritance-method-call-triggers-typescript-compiler-error) is precisely the use of the arrow functions.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on any version available in the playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsKBTAdhAMID2AtgA4n4GIDeAUAswhVAJYBuwEuCA+mFzJc8XABMAXAhAkSI4PgQBeBADNgyIQG4GTFhQCuIZO1gIA5rkRCRY8QAoAlNNnzcihIxY+EeCIZQShAAFuxgAHSCwqK84ro+AL76zEYmZghCNjH2DtzIhriucgr4Tl4pvqHhUbaxEioI+YUJLMnJDKCQMPBIqOgIRGHI4qSU1LQIuAAevPjiGNh4hGNUNIQVPlbZdnHOxe6e3r7M-oFKYIYUuFARdfatzMk+WZk5e-dxB6XlxyeX11unwaqmB8Uq7T0KDQGAAGlNZgQFoNhqNyGtJowGB1YNRIAhgI0aAB3BCw5y6YB3d4ghDQFqdERQCAOKlgpzaIA

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I can't reproduce it on the playground too. Moreover, it is reproduced only with "ng build --configuration=production --stats-json" script. With "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js" it is doesn't reproduce and all compile successfully

Comment: Then I assume it must be from some other code and/or configuration you've not shared with us.

Answer (score 0):

[In Angular CLI version 8 and higher, differential loading is enabled by default for the ng build command](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading). As a result, this produces two builds, and differential loading is enabled. If you ignore browsers without ES2015 support, a single build is produced.

You can do this by setting **.browserlistrc** to ignore or include browsers that you needed. Otherwise you can add the **"browserslist"** field to your **package.json**.